# How to add extra whitespace between section header and a paragraph

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to have more space between the header and the paragraph and between the paragraphs. I doesn't want this to be a global setting but I want to use it where and when required. Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use vertical bars at the beginning of lines to produce blank lines in the output. Like this:

```
Heading
-------

|
|

Paragraph with text.
```

Comment: For LaTeX output, this adds far too much spacing, even when just used with a single pipe character.  Seems the LaTeX ``DUlineblock`` that gets generated defaults to 2.5em height, and with paragraph spacing results in a lot more space than just one line.

Answer (score 17):

I just had this problem and as davidjb pointed out, using `|` gives you too much space on LaTeX output. This is how I solved it. Define the following:

```
.. |vspace| raw:: latex

   \vspace{5mm}
```

Then you can just use `|vspace|` on the places where you want the vertical space to get appropriate vertical space.

If you want spaces in html output as well, you can define:

```
.. |vspace| raw:: latex

   \vspace{5mm}

.. |br| raw:: html

   <br />
```

Then when you need the space, simply put:

```
|vspace| |br|
```

and it will automatically take care of the spacing depending on the output format.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, it's just solved the same issue that I was seeing.