# How to insert a blank line in restructured text?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm drafting a document using Sphinx 1.1.3.
When I insert two tables one after another, those tables show up too close in HTML, so I want to insert a blank line between them. How do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add extra whitespace between section header and a paragraph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218039/how-to-add-extra-whitespace-between-section-header-and-a-paragraph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possible solutions:

1. Use @mzjn's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641905/how-to-insert-a-blank-line-in-restructured-text#comment23941937_16641905)
2. Create a custom CSS stylesheet that will define padding beneath a table (or above, or both).

Answer (score 11):

You can use vertical bars at the beginning of lines to produce blank lines in the output. Like this:

```
Heading
-------

|
|

Paragraph with text.
```