# How insert some space before and after images in Sphinx

Tags: latex, line-breaks, python-sphinx

I created a document via Sphinx with the `make latexpdf` command.

Now I have the problem that LaTeX is setting my picture at the top directly after the text and at the bottom of the image it puts 3 or 4 linebreaks.

Is there a possibility to get 1 space at the top and 1 space at the bottom of the picture without
having to use a  `\` in the syntax?

My code:

```
title:
===========

some text

.. image:: screenshots/manage_products.png

some more text

another title:
===========
```

EDIT: Here a little Screenshot to show you my problem. I also looked into the main documentation of Sphinx (+ Syntax documentation) and found no answer for this problem!

[image]

Btw: Ignore the red arrow plz.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8218320/407651

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the .. figure:: directive to add the extra spacing you would like around your image.

```
title:
===========

some text

.. figure:: screenshots/manage_products.png

some more text
```

I like using the figure directive more as well, since you have some additional control elements to your image, such as labeling.

```
.. figure::

   Your figure text here
```

Comment: It's working fine, I wont use the .. image:: command anymore!

Comment: I am using `make latexpdf` to generate pdf file from my Sphinx project. However I am running into image insertion issue. Could you please check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63452024/how-to-include-image-files-in-sphinx-latex-pdf-files) here?

Answer (score -2):

Wanted to add a narrow line after the image and tried all sorts of combinations and all either did not work or gave a wide line after the image.

Ended up creating a tiny empty.png image and inserted into the page with the following:

```
.. image:: _static/main.png 
    :align: center
    :scale: 70 %    

.. image:: _static/empty.png 
.. empty.png image above to add space after main.png image
```

Comment: hacky, and not what the op asked for