# How to control spacing after an image in a rst document

Tags: restructuredtext

I am writing a document using reStructuredText (reST). When I add an image, using for example:

```
.. image:: ..\\images\\myfig.png
   :width: 420
   :align: center

New paragraph continues here
```

No spacing in added after the image so a new paragraph is right up against the image. One way to add space is to use, | as in:

```
.. image:: ..\\images\\myfig.png
   :width: 420
   :align: center

|

New paragraph continues here
```

But this leaves far too much space. Is there another way to control vertical space in a rst document?

There is one stackoverflow related question from 2019 ([How insert some space before and after images in Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882788/how-insert-some-space-before-and-after-images-in-sphinx)) but it uses a hack to add spacing by using an empty image for padding. Another idea is to add white space padding to the actual image, but that is another hack. Perhaps in 2023, there is better solution?

Comment: Use custom CSS.

Comment: The [reST image directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image) doesn't give you any further options, so custom CSS is the way to go. You can insert some other construct like the vertical pipe to try and align things but that alignment is also a result of the default CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In plain Docutils, there is a 0.5em margin above the next paragraph.

If some other converter or style sheet does not insert any space, consider a bug report.

If you want more space custom CSS is the way to go.
You may also define classes for different amount of padding, e.g.

```
.. image:: ..\\images\\myfig.png
   :width: 420
   :align: center
   :class: largepadding
```

and a custom CSS rule
`img.largepadding {padding: 2em;}`.